# Check out document to the document author at the end of the workflow

Tags: workflow

I am very new to workflows so I would appreciate any help. I have a standard approval workflow that I wish to change. When the workflow completes I would like the document to be checked out to the document owner/author, is this possible?

Comment: Hi Mike, welcome to the SP.SE community! Which version of SharePoint are you using? Are you creating this workflow through the browser, or in another program like SharePoint Designer or Visual Studio?

Comment: Thanks for the welcome. Currently using 2010 enterprise but we are going to downgrade to standard. The workflow has already been created. It's an approval workflow I want to tag onto the end the checking out process.

Answer (score 3):

By default, a workflow is run under the security permissions of the workflow initiator.
The CheckOut action doesn't let you specify who the item should be checked out to. It will be checked out to the user under which the workflow is running, which is the workflow initiator or the workflow author, when an impersonation step is used.

(more info on this on [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee428324.aspx#BKMK_Workflowconfigurationsettings))

So, the short answer is no, you cannot with an OOTB workflow, unless the workflow initiator is the same document owner/author.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the workflow initiator is the owner/author as they would start the approval workflow process???

Comment: Ok, so it's enough to add a Check Out item action and the document should result checked out to its author

Comment: @MikeBlair I see you haven't accepted any answer so far. Please remember to upvote and mark as accepted those answers you found helpful. This will benefit both the answerer and the community. Thanks!